# What causes this error deserializing XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am getting the following error while deserializing an XML in C# despite having listed this namespace on the XMLType and XMLRoot attributes in my class.

```
<ProductRegistrationInterface xmlns='http://www.4cs.com/CLMSchema'> was not expected.
```

The XML looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ns4CS:ProductRegistrationInterface 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns4CS="http://www.4cs.com/CLMSchema">
    <ns4CS:MessageHeader>
      <TargetReference>Some Value</TargetReference>
    </ns4CS:MessageHeader>
    <ProductRegistrations>
      <ProductRegistration>...</ProductRegistration>
      <ProductRegistration>...</ProductRegistration>
      <ProductRegistration>...</ProductRegistration>
    </ProductRegistrations>
  </ns4CS:ProductRegistrationInterface>
```

The ProductRegistrationInterface class looks like:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.4cs.com/CLMSchema")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.4cs.com/CLMSchema", IsNullable = false)]
public class ProductRegistrationInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of <see cref="ProductRegistration"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlArray(Namespace = "")]
    [XmlArrayItem(nameof(ProductRegistration), IsNullable = false)]
    public ProductRegistration[] ProductRegistrations { get; set; }        
}
```

And finally here is the code I am using:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductRegistrationInfo));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Test.xml");
ProductRegistrationInfo s = (ProductRegistrationInfo)xs.Deserialize(sr);
sr.Close();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The error uses a different quote (`'`) than the posted code (`"`). Can you check both?

Comment: I think it was an issue with how the error message was showing in the post. I have corrected that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type mismatch: you are attempting to deserialize into an instance of type ProjectRegistration**Interface**, but using a serializer created for the type ProductRegistration**Info**.

Comment: That was it. I don't know how I didn't see that earlier. Thanks.